# MFA phone number does not appears in token claims after sign up

Tags: multi-factor-authentication, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i have applied the MFA on sign up using custom policies following this [MFA using custom policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa),
MFA working fine,

i have added following claim in relying party

```html
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="phone_number" />
```

but i am not getting strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber as claim after sign up, but when i sign in  with this created account it shows in the claims.
i want to have strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber in claims immediately after sign up.
i am using jwt.ms for quick viewing of claims

Answer (score 1):

Add below ClaimType in ClaimsSchema

```
 <ClaimType Id="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber">
        <DisplayName>Phone Number</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <Mask Type="Simple">XXX-XXX-</Mask>
        <UserHelpText>Your telephone number</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber">
        <DisplayName>Verified Phone Number</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="phone_number" />
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Mask Type="Simple">XXX-XXX-</Mask>
        <UserHelpText>Your office phone number that has been verified</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
```

ADD OutputClaim in "AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfile as below

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId">
              <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber"/>
 </OutputClaims>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add PersistedClaim in "AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" TechnicalProfile as below

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
<PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
</PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add OutputClaim in "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" TechnicalProfile

```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
<OutputClaims> 
               <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber"/>
</OutputClaims>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add PersistedClaim in "AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" as below

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
<PersistedClaims>
 <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
 
          </PersistedClaims>

        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add PersistedClaim in "AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId" as below

```
   <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId">        
          <PersistedClaims>        
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <!-- If the user stepped up during password reset, their phone number should be persisted for future authentication requests. -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />     
          </PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add OutputClaim in "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId"

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">        
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />         
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add PersistedClaim in "AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" as below

```
  <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add outputClaim in "LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" TechnicalProfile as below

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">       
         <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add InputClaim in "LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" TechnicalProfile as below

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">       
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </InputClaims>        
   </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add OutputClaim in login-NonInteractive

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
      <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Also, add Outputclaim in RelyingParty in the SignUpOrSignIn policy

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="phone_number" />
```

this will surely give you the phone number in token after SignIN.
helping material: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa

Comment: I have already added these all, and already followed this GitHub sample for MFA you mentioned. and I am getting this claim on sign in with no issue, problem is that, I want to get this claim after sign UP.

Comment: For SignUp in your base policy file add Outputclaim in "SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" and "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" TechnicalProfile after this add Outputclaim in RelyingParty in the SignUpOrSignIn policy file
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />

Comment: ok, i will try this solution as well and let you know how it goes, but for now i added <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" /> in relying party and it returned as phone_number. is this solution correct?? can i do this like so as it is returning the Phone Number on sign up. or should i go with your solution to make change in base policy file?

Comment: try <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" /> in SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" and "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" and then check

Answer (score 0):

Since you have kept the Partner claim type as phone_number, it should be visible as phone_number in the jwt token.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: yes it is, but the question was can i use "Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" in place of "strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" ?